# How set user-defined values in the `vim.bo` namespace?

Tags: lua, neovim

### Introduction

Migrating little by little from vimscript to lua, I wanted to create a `usermessage` variable that I could set in a function call. For instance:

```
fun! ShowHiGroup()
  " set statusline+=%{HiGroup()}
  lua vim.bo["usermessage"] = '%{HiGroup()}'
  echom  "Activated show highlight group"
endfun
```

It would be read by my status line rendering function when the value is set (so it's a "maybe usermessage").

I tried naively to set `vim.bo["usermessage"]` and received "invalid option value".

### Question

Is there a buffer namespace I can use to set user-defined values?